# "in_time_zone" changes timezone for past date

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime, timezone

I am using [in_time_zone](https://apidock.com/rails/DateTime/in_time_zone) method of ruby to convert the time in required timezone.

When the date is in past it is changing the Time Zone which is unexpected.

**process_date** : is column of table where I store the DateTime

Here is snippet

```
2.5.5 :500 > @time_zone
 => "Eastern Time (US & Canada)" 
2.5.5 :501 > future_transaction.process_date
 => Sat, 30 Nov 2019 03:59:11 UTC +00:00 
2.5.5 :502 > DateTime.parse(future_transaction.process_date.to_s).in_time_zone(@time_zone).strftime("%m/%d/%Y %r %Z")
 => "11/29/2019 10:59:11 PM EST" # << here it is EST
2.5.5 :503 > past_transaction.process_date
 => Sat, 02 Nov 2019 09:38:00 UTC +00:00 
2.5.5 :504 > DateTime.parse(past_transaction.process_date.to_s).in_time_zone(@time_zone).strftime("%m/%d/%Y %r %Z")
 => "11/02/2019 05:38:00 AM EDT" # << here it is EDT becasue of past date
2.5.5 :505 >
```

Can anybody tell me what's wrong with my approach .

Comment: Please see "[ask]", "[Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648)" and "[MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)" and all their linked pages. We need the minimal code in the question itself that demonstrates the problem. We _can_ work it out from the IRB session but that's not what SO wants.

Comment: There is no `in_time_zone` method in [tag:ruby].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because of summer and winter time. This year EDT was changed to EST on 3rd November. So it's not a bug, it's a feature :)